# Old school Multiboot question - Booting from USB to a installed drive with linux installed on it?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, lubuntu

*First off - feel free to laugh or shout about this, but please do it in private.*

Years ago when I was first using Linux and windows together, we used used a floppy disk to hold a boot manager pointing to a secondary HD with a Linux distro. I believe it was using grub, If I had a working 5-1/4" drive I would check one of these old disks.

This allowed me have a Linux OS tucked away on a partition or secondary drive and still keep the native OS boot manger untouched. So if the floppy disk was not inserted, the original OS would boot. I often used this to rebuild training rooms systems from a snapshot stored within a Slackware partition.

Is there a modern equivalent of this tactic with out having to build a custom ISO or installing full Linux distro to a USB? I just need the boot manager to be on a USB memory stick or CD to point to an installation on a secondary drive.   Currently there is no need to even boot to the existing native OS on the system when the USB memory stick or CD is in.

Comment: I think yes. You can install Ubuntu's `/` partition on a secondary drive and you can install the bootloader in the USB instead of your harddisk.

Comment: You can just install grub to MBR of flash drive using Something Else, or install /boot as separate partition on flash drive. I often create flash drives with just grub and manually add my own grub.cfg to loopmount several ISO for install or repair, but have entries to also boot one or two of my installs on hard drive. But Ubuntu makes it difficult to not install grub to a MBR usually sda. If a new UEFI system a bit different but possible.